# A sandboxed version of Haskell

Tags: haskell, sandbox

Is there a sandboxed version of Haskell that prevents dangerous code from being run? I stumbled across [mueval](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mueval-0.4.6) and [Safe Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/SafeHaskell/)...mueval only takes expressions, and Safe Haskell hasn't been implemented yet. Is there some other alternative for sandboxing Haskell scripts? It seems like preventing IO should be enough. Is there an easy way to prevent all IO in a Haskell script?

Comment: Safe Haskell is available since GHC 7.2 (although AFAIR it wasn't working too well in 7.2, so you should use 7.4 if you want it). http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/safe-haskell.html

Comment: If you prevent all IO, then what can your Haskell script actually *do*? Compute its heart out, only to *not* be able to convey the result to anything?

Comment: @DanBurton sounds weird, but in this case that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Safe Haskell](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/safe-haskell.html) is the latest incarnation of a trusted core for Haskell, and is available in the Haskell Platform.

It exists to facilitate the execution of untrusted code.